# CRUD itself in OOP design

Tags: entity-framework, oop, design-patterns

I just started learning web programming. When I design class diagram for Leave Online Management system.
I I looked at this tutorial and started to get confused about my OOP knowledge. [image]

I think, an object has only actions that it can do in the same way as it actually does. A `Cow` cannot milk itself. That must have 1 object like `Farmer` take milk from `Cow` or `Farmer` kill `Cow`(delete), change `Cow`(update). But my boss said that an object itself CRUD itself, it is OOP. **The cow milked itself**. I think `Task` cann't CRUD itself(exclude Create - Constructor). I think need a object like `TaskManager` for CRUD `TASK`. Where am I misunderstanding? Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you so much .!!!

P/s: Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But my boss said that an object itself CRUD itself, it is OOP

What he's describing is called the [Active Record Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html).  In practice it's got significant downsides, and the [Repository Pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is now much more common.

Entity Framework implements the Repository Pattern, as the DbContext is a Repository that enables query, change tracking, and CRUD for the entity objects.

Entities can have methods and responsibilities in the Repository Pattern, but CRUD is handled by the repository.

Comment: That means my understanding of OOP is right ?. What my boss said was just a pattern. If my boss says "that is OOP nature" then it's wrong or right

Comment: BTW... Thank you so much

Comment: The core idea of OOP is to encapsulate data and behavior into objects.  Both patterns are OOP patterns.